# Laravel 8 HTTP API POST response empty

Tags: laravel, api

I am getting blank when post data( username and password ) to the external api using the laravel controller.

The api is working on postman tool and returns the success status with a user data. Here post the username and password to the body.

web.php

```
Route::get('/myuser', [MyUserController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('/myuser/checklogin', [MyUserController::class, 'checklogin'])->name('myuser.checklogin');
```

MyUserContoller.php

```
$response = Http::post('https://api.com/login', array(
                'headers'   => array('Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data'),
                'body'      => array( 'username' => 'testadmin1', 'password' => 'admin1' )
            ));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a response in MyUserController, this could be for example:

```php
$response = Http::post('https://api.com/login', array(
                'headers'   => array('Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data'),
                'body'      => array( 'username' => 'testadmin1', 'password' => 'admin1' )
            ));
 return response($response->body());
```

Doing so will then return the response data from your post request

Comment: I print the response data that returns the empty. That's why

Comment: @GovindChinnasamy, can you update your question to show the code that returns the response data, please?